# Continuous timer with stop/resume that saves time

Tags: jquery, timer, resume

I want to create a continuous timer that I can pause and resume at a later time.
After each start and stop the elapsed time should be saved in a txt/csv file (or any other practical way). When the website is reloaded/revisited the time displayed should be the sum of all previous times and as soon as you hit a resume button the timer continues.

I have tried using the [Keith Woods jQuery Countdown examples](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html), but unfortunately I cannot wrap my head around it. I open to other solutions...

[Edit] Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rkLPlr7pScHXDS4EG7tA?p=preview

```
$(function () {
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
$('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
```

Comment: If you want some data to persist after reloading the page and have this data shared for multiple users you might need to consider some serverside solutions. For one user, you might be able to store this data in localstorage/cookies.

Comment: _JavaScript_ doesn't give you general filesystem access. You can initiate a download of a (even generated) `.txt` or `.csv` file, but you can't choose where this file goes, what it's ultimately called or automatically load it back when the user next visits your page

Comment: Its not for one user only. I want to host this on my personal webspace....I would be fine with any other way to store the time....